# Background Page Doesn't Show as Active User

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I added Google Analytics to a Chrome Extension. It is reporting events correctly as well as recording popup page views. When the extension is reloaded it correctly records a view of background.html which I explicitly call.

**Problem:** Despite the extension having a persistent background.html page, "Active Users" in the Real-Time section of GA shows 0. I would like to be able to see the # of concurrent users of the extension at a given time. Is there a way to do it?

**Possible Solution?** - When I open the popup it displays an active user for some number of minutes before dropping back down to zero. Do I need to create a heartbeat function of some kind that pings GA every X minutes to keep a user active. It seems a big "chatty" to do that.

Is there a better solution?